# Astyanax - TokenRangeOfflineException when trying to connect to cassandra

Tags: cassandra, playorm, astyanax

This is how I am connecting to Cassandra, by Astyanax:

```
Builder builder = new AstyanaxContext.Builder()
        .forCluster(clusterName)
        .forKeyspace(keyspace2)
        .withAstyanaxConfiguration(new AstyanaxConfigurationImpl()      
            .setDiscoveryType(NodeDiscoveryType.RING_DESCRIBE)
        )
        .withConnectionPoolConfiguration(new ConnectionPoolConfigurationImpl("MyConnectionPool")
            .setMaxConnsPerHost(2)
            .setInitConnsPerHost(2)
            .setSeeds("localhost,localhost")
        )
        .withConnectionPoolMonitor(new CountingConnectionPoolMonitor());
            AstyanaxConfigurationImpl config = new AstyanaxConfigurationImpl();
        config.setDefaultWriteConsistencyLevel(ConsistencyLevel.CL_QUORUM);
        config.setDefaultReadConsistencyLevel(ConsistencyLevel.CL_QUORUM);
        builder = builder.withAstyanaxConfiguration(config);
```

If in seeds I put just "localhost", it works fine.
If I put "localhost,localhost" or "localhost," it gives me the exception bellow. 
What could I be missing? The problem is not the host, the address is correct... If I use CL_Quorum, is there any config I should be aware about?

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.netflix.astyanax.connectionpool.exceptions.TokenRangeOfflineException: TokenRangeOfflineException: [host=localhost(127.0.0.1):9160, latency=10(10), attempts=1] UnavailableException()
    at com.alvazan.orm.layer9z.spi.db.cassandra.CursorKeysToRows.execute(CursorKeysToRows.java:157)
    at com.alvazan.orm.layer9z.spi.db.cassandra.CursorKeysToRows.loadCache(CursorKeysToRows.java:100)
    at com.alvazan.orm.layer9z.spi.db.cassandra.CursorKeysToRows.nextImpl(CursorKeysToRows.java:65)
    at com.alvazan.orm.layer0.base.CursorRow.nextImpl(CursorRow.java:33)
    at com.alvazan.orm.api.z8spi.iter.AbstractCursor.next(AbstractCursor.java:10)
    at com.alvazan.orm.layer0.base.BaseEntityManagerImpl.find(BaseEntityManagerImpl.java:132)
    at com.alvazan.orm.layer0.base.BaseEntityManagerImpl.saveMetaData(BaseEntityManagerImpl.java:235)
    at com.alvazan.orm.layer0.base.BaseEntityManagerFactoryImpl.rescan(BaseEntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:102)
    at com.alvazan.orm.layer0.base.BaseEntityManagerFactoryImpl.setup(BaseEntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:131)
    at com.alvazan.orm.impl.bindings.BootstrapImpl.createInstanceImpl(BootstrapImpl.java:64)
    at com.alvazan.orm.impl.bindings.BootstrapImpl.createInstance(BootstrapImpl.java:35)
    at com.alvazan.orm.api.base.Bootstrap.create(Bootstrap.java:57)
    at com.alvazan.orm.api.base.Bootstrap.create(Bootstrap.java:52)
    at com.alvazan.orm.api.base.Bootstrap.create(Bootstrap.java:45)
    at com.alvazan.orm.api.base.Bootstrap.create(Bootstrap.java:24)
    at com.s1mbi0se.dmp.da.dao.PlayOrmConfiguration.init(PlayOrmConfiguration.java:39)
    at com.s1mbi0se.dmp.da.dao.TestUserDao.testFindAllUsers(TestUserDao.java:73)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: com.netflix.astyanax.connectionpool.exceptions.TokenRangeOfflineException: TokenRangeOfflineException: [host=localhost(127.0.0.1):9160, latency=10(10), attempts=1] UnavailableException()
    at com.netflix.astyanax.thrift.ThriftConverter.ToConnectionPoolException(ThriftConverter.java:165)
    at com.netflix.astyanax.thrift.AbstractOperationImpl.execute(AbstractOperationImpl.java:60)
    at com.netflix.astyanax.thrift.AbstractOperationImpl.execute(AbstractOperationImpl.java:27)
    at com.netflix.astyanax.thrift.ThriftSyncConnectionFactoryImpl$1.execute(ThriftSyncConnectionFactoryImpl.java:131)
    at com.netflix.astyanax.connectionpool.impl.AbstractExecuteWithFailoverImpl.tryOperation(AbstractExecuteWithFailoverImpl.java:52)
    at com.netflix.astyanax.connectionpool.impl.AbstractHostPartitionConnectionPool.executeWithFailover(AbstractHostPartitionConnectionPool.java:229)
    at com.netflix.astyanax.thrift.ThriftColumnFamilyQueryImpl$4.execute(ThriftColumnFamilyQueryImpl.java:457)
    at com.alvazan.orm.layer9z.spi.db.cassandra.CursorKeysToRows.execute(CursorKeysToRows.java:155)
    ... 39 more
Caused by: UnavailableException()
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$multiget_slice_result.read(Cassandra.java:9722)
    at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:78)
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Client.recv_multiget_slice(Cassandra.java:613)
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Client.multiget_slice(Cassandra.java:597)
    at com.netflix.astyanax.thrift.ThriftColumnFamilyQueryImpl$4$1.internalExecute(ThriftColumnFamilyQueryImpl.java:463)
    at com.netflix.astyanax.thrift.ThriftColumnFamilyQueryImpl$4$1.internalExecute(ThriftColumnFamilyQueryImpl.java:460)
    at com.netflix.astyanax.thrift.AbstractOperationImpl.execute(AbstractOperationImpl.java:55)
    ... 45 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is related to the other question.  You only want to use localhost OR a list of seeds.  We basically do some detection and if you only use one node, we use CL_ONE for consistency when using localhost or writes and reads fail.  We do CL_QUOROM for 2 or more seeds.  Do you need us to modify this to support one single remote node?

thanks,
Dean